# How to detect all executable file in windows including(exe, dll, msi, vxd, sys and etc)

Tags: winapi

I want to detect all the executable files regardless of the file extension.
I tried to do this with `GetBinaryType` but this API just detect `.EXE` and `.COM` file. How to detect all executable file.

```
DWORD binaryType;
if(GetBinaryType("1.dll",&binaryType))
{
    if(binaryType >= 0 && binaryType < 7)
         cout << "ok";
}
```

Comment: but ... dll's aren't executable.

Comment: Why not use regex to detect if it's one of them? But of course it won't work if you change it's extension to something else other than those.

Comment: file structure and header of dll file similar to exe file @UKMonkey

Comment: Look at the documentation of this API: ``Determines whether a file is an executable (.exe) file, and if so, which subsystem runs the executable file.``

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. What are you trying to accomplish, and why do you believe, that your attempt would be part of the solution?

Comment: i want to create a file filter and can not trust this one @Asesh

Comment: So, open the file and look for the PE header.

Comment: OK for example .COM file header very different with .exe file @DavidHeffernan

Comment: And what makes you think that you could do better than pre-existing solutions, written by teams with literally decades of experience on the subject of security?

Comment: Please identify one of these @IInspectable

Comment: @mamadymadani you want to detect multiple file types - you will have to run multiple tests, one for each file type that you're interested in.  It's a bit like asking how to detect all image types ....

Comment: NO if you look at all executable file you will find out they are very similar @UKMonkey

Comment: so you want detect are file is valid `PE` format file or what ?

Comment: yes I want to detect witch file may be run in my windows @RbMm

Comment: no, i ask not about this. i ask about are you look for any `PE` format. *be run in my windows* - this is unclear. unclear about what you asking

Comment: it is very simple. just i want to detect all PE format. I did not ask about Einstein's relativity law!!!! @RbMm

Comment: You can run files, that aren't executables themselves, e.g. PowerShell scripts, HTML documents with embedded JavaScript code, or PFF files with active content. It's unclear, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: so any `PE` format ? exe, dll, driver, both 32 and 64 bits, even on 32 bit windows ? because *file may be run in my windows* make unclear your question

Comment: If you want to detect the PE format, then open the file and look for the PE header. I already said that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - better after open file call `CreateFileMapping` with `SEC_IMAGE` option. exactly this do `GetBinaryType`. only for valid pe file section will be created. system yourself check this.

Comment: Thanks. it works.@RbMm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file call `CreateFileMapping` with `SEC_IMAGE` option. exactly this do `GetBinaryType`. only for valid pe file section will be created.@RbMm

This work.

```
HANDLE file=CreateFile("example.dll",GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
HANDLE mapFile=CreateFileMapping(file,NULL,PAGE_READ_ONLY|SEC_IMAGE,0,0,0);
int err=GetLastError();
```

if `err` equal by 0, input file is pe; but this method not work for `.msi` file.

Comment: .msi files aren't executable files. Your question still doesn't explain, which files exactly you want to detect. If *"file may be run in my windows"* is what you really want to detect, then there are boat loads of other file types that meet that requirement (like PowerShell scripts).